# TLS: how do we distribute root CA to clients?

Tags: tls

I am trying to understand TLS authentication mechanisms.

So my basic understanding is:

```
Server has private key and TLS certificate(issued by some CA).
During TLS handshake, client asks server for certificate.
Server hands over certificate to client
Client verifies server certificate with root ca that issued server certificate.
```

I want to understand how does client get access to root ca.

Is it distributed to clients offline? Or is it stored in some database that client accesses?

Comment: In short: they come with the OS and/or the client software.